# How to get Person Id using peoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone

in my application i am using peoplePickerNavigationController

I want to get person Id

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{

in this method how can i get the person id or any other values like phone number n first name etc...

Please help me

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Apple's sample app.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html) it will demonstrate how to get the person's name and other properties. Also, if you want to edit a property in the address book, check my [tutorial](http://salemsayed.me/?p=109).